# Is there a fix to my into statement error?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

This is my code

```
    Private Sub Guna2Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button1.Click
    Dim pop As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
    If pop.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Guna2CirclePictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(pop.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Sub save()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into Table1('firstname','lastname','username','password','dob','role','status','pic') values(@firstname,@lastname,@username,@password,@dob,@role,@status,@pic)", conn)
        Dim i As New Integer
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", Guna2TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", Guna2TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Guna2TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Guna2TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", CDate(Guna2DateTimePicker1.Value))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", Guna2ComboBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", CBool(Guna2CheckBox2.Checked.ToString))

        'image convert to binary formate

        Dim FileSize As UInt32
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Guna2CirclePictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim picture() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer
        FileSize = mstream.Length
        mstream.Close()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", picture)

        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("You are now a registered member.", vbInformation)

        Else
            MsgBox("Registration Failed. Try Again.", vbCritical)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

It says type "firstname" correctly but I did. It is also the same field name in my access database. I hope you could help me with my problem. I promise to be responsive. Thank you.

Comment: Try without the single quotes around the field names.

Answer (score 1):

Also, *Password* is a reserved word:

```
"insert into Table1(firstname,lastname,username,[password],dob,role,[status],pic) values(@firstname,@lastname,@username,@password,@dob,@role,@status,@pic)"
```

and DateTimePicker returns a DateTime value:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Guna2DateTimePicker1.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", Guna2CheckBox2.Checked)
```

Comment: it says datatype mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: It could be the same issue for the _status_ field. See extended answer, please. However, we don't have your table, neither the scheme, so you must debug and double-check data types.